# Write event on class selector on Angular 5

Tags: angular

Hi this is my function

```
 $('body').on('focus', '.floating-input', function () {
                $(this).siblings('label').addClass('moveUp');
                console.log("Mano");
            });
```

This is written inside **ngOnInit()** and **ngAfterViewInit()** which is working fine in chrome and firefox, but the same is not working in IE and Safari. I wanted to *skip writing jQuery code* inside Angular 2. Is there any other option or Please help me find what`s wrong.

Comment: Can `(focus)="focusFunction()" ` help?

Comment: No, because I`ll have to add for every control

Comment: @mano10 then add a directive to add behaviors.

Comment: How about `document.getElementsByClassName("floating-input")` , iterate list and add class?

Comment: Add a directive??

Comment: Iteration won`t help I guess, because class should be added on focus only

Comment: You should either use a custom directive or do smth like this `<input (focus)="focusFunction(input)"  #input />`